# code name one action bar

Tags: android, codenameone

[image]how to create actionbar in codenameone?
I have tried with commandBehaviour= Title it works but there is problem in bg color of title .
as shown in images . (i have also added bgcolor of title) so how to make same color in whole title background ?
[image: title bg in iphone]

[image: title bg in nexus]

Comment: add here your code also

Comment: you can  see  commandBehaviour= Title 
and set command in form from designer (thats sufficient)

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch the command behavior and when you run on the physical Android device (OS 3 or newer) you will get the actionbar. We can't simulate it properly since its native.

Comment: I have removed the commandbehaviour and 
I have tested on samsung tab3 (which is higher than 3) , the command does not show in action bar. the command is shown when menu is clicked. And I want to show always in title as action bar

Comment: That is the default for Android 4. If you want the command to appear in the title bar you can use the command hints such as:
cmd.putClientProperty("android:showAsAction", "withText");
Or as the key "always", "withIcon" etc.

Comment: using "always" also have same title background color problem , I have set red color for title bg using designer but grey color is displaying why?

how to remove that grey ?

Comment: That's a native title so it uses the native OS color scheme. You can either use your own title or the native title.